# redux - change id of javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, store, identifier

I have a store which looks like:

```
[object]
  0: Object 
    001: object 
      completed: false
```

My question:  I'd like the 001 id to replace the 0 id - how can i achieve this?

My reducer for this is :

```
if (action.type === 'ADD_USER') {
  const nextState = [
    ...state, {
      [action.userId]: {
        ['domain']: action.domain,
        ['version']: action.version,
        ['completed'] : false
      }
    }
  ]
  return nextState
}
```

Comment: If you're going to change the key every time, do you have access to what the old key (they key you are changing) is? In this case it's `001`, but how will you know what it is after a few uses of this reducer?

Comment: This seems like a problem that can be solved with a clearer code layout. Can you edit your question and explain what you are trying to achieve/for what purpose?

Comment: These are not "ids". They are KEYS or PROPERTY NAMES.

Comment: And this is not an array, it's an OBJECT.